# Java Synchronisation with and without static variable

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I have been studying about synchronization in java and tried to run the following program

```
    public class Example {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Counter counterA = new Counter();
            Counter counterB = new Counter();
              Thread  threadA = new CounterThread(counterA);
              Thread  threadB = new CounterThread(counterB);

              threadA.start();
              threadB.start(); 
        }
    }

    class CounterThread extends Thread {
        protected Counter counter = null;

        public CounterThread(Counter counter){
           this.counter = counter;
        }
        public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
              counter.add(i);
           }
        }
    }

    class Counter {
         long count = 0;
         public synchronized void add(long value){
          this.count += value;
          System.out.println(this.count);
        }
    }
```

when i run the above code , it gives me the same output when i run Example class as java application or when i  debug the Example class

```
 0
 1
 0
 1
```

But if i modify the access modifier of count variable of counter class as static like mentioned below :

```
    static long count = 0;
```

and now if try to run the Example class i get the output as

```
 0
 1
 0
 2
```

but when i debug the Example class i get the output as

```
 0
 1
 1
 2
```

Can anyone help me to understand the difference. 
Thanks in advance and apologies because i am new to multithreading concepts

Answer (score 0):

Each instance has its own copy of instance variable(s) but they share the static variable. As you have two instances of your class and two threads operating on these instances:

```
        Counter counterA = new Counter();
        Counter counterB = new Counter();
        Thread  threadA = new CounterThread(counterA);
        Thread  threadB = new CounterThread(counterB);
```

So the effect is clear. When the `count` is non-static, two threads do not affect the `count` of two different objects. But when `count` is static, two threads work on the same variable shared by two instances.

When you have two independent threads in action, the execution order is dynamic depending on how Thread Scheduler picks a thread to execute. Using a debugger not necessarily does affect it , infact you may see different result with normal execution of your program.

Comment: but in case when count is static then normal execution and debugger execution should give the same results ?

Comment: @user3403462 How does a static variable can effect the thread scheduler? makes no sense and there is no connection.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` only protects you from two callers entering a method *on the same instance* at the same time. So it basically does not affect your example at all.

Non-static case: Each thread is updating its own `Counter.count` instance. You can get either 0-1-0-1 or 0-0-1-1 (much less likely) as output.

Static case: Each thread is updating the same `Counter.count` via two *different* `Counter` instances. You can get either 0-0-1-2, 0-1-1-2 AND 0-1-0-2.

Why the last option? You only affect a static `Coutner.count` instance, not a static `Counter` instance. So both threads can be inside `Counter.add` and one thread may have already loaded 0 for outputting it, but the other threads then updates it and outputs 1 and only then the first thread outputs its 0.

Which of 0-0-1-2, 0-1-1-2 or 0-1-0-2 you get is not defined at all and does *NOT* depend on debug & release modes. It is quite common, however, to receive different results in debug & release modes due to differences in the assembly code produced by the compiler.